# Mapping datapoints over several floors of a building

Tags: carto, visualisation, indoor, torque

I'm new to web mapping and am planning and investigating ways on how to best plot and visualize user flow through a building across several floors.

We are planning on tracking users location based on proximity to iBeacons. Each data point will track both time and location (based on proximity to the iBeacon). We're considering building a torque visualization to demonstrate how users flow through and use the building.

How would you recommend best visualizing this data and representing the multiple (4) floors to see user flow around the building (hopefully on one map).

Answer (score 2):

CartoDB doesn't know about a "z dimension", but you will be able to build something similar by playing with the zoom levels.

Directly in the editor:
  Built a Torque Category map by a column which contains the floors. Then, you can use a code like the following one to hide the other floors in the specified zoom to set for a floor.
  `#table[value=2] {
     marker-fill: #1F78B4;
    #table[zoom=7] {
      marker-width: 0;
    }
  }`

You can then use CartoDB.js to lock the maximum and minimum level of zoom (to avoid users going to zoom levels that doesn't correspond to your floors), and, for example, instead of change the zoom with the scroll, change it with some buttons you can build.